# Data Transfer between 2 workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer data from one workbook to another. The destination workbook is changing it's name every day according to the date.
I used this code:

```vba
Dim MyMonth,MyYear,MyCage

 MyMonth = MonthName(Month(Date))
 MyYear = Year(Date)
 MyCage = "MainTest" & " " & MyDate
 My Date=Format(Date,"dd-mm-yyyy")

Dim MyFile As Workbook

Set MyFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\VBA1MC\MyYear\TestMC\MyMonth\MyCage")`
```

It gives me a runtime error 1004.
But when I change the 3 variables(MyYear,MyMonth,MyCage) to 2018,February,MainTest 08-02-2018 which gives me:

```
'Set MyFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\VBA1MC\2018\TestMC\February\MainTest 08-02-2018")'
```

it works. What did I do wrong with the variables?

Comment: I do not see a line where you fill MyDate?

Comment: Sorry I missed it in the question but in the code I have it as follow:

Comment: Ok, edited the code below accordingly. I assume the blank in "My Date" is by mistake. If you want to add your variables inside a string you have to put the string together in a different way, see below.